# check checkbox on click href and on click checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I know there is many topics for check a checkbox by clicking on href, but in every solution i seen, you can't check the checkbox by clicking on the checkbox, because it wrapped by the `<a>` tag.

**There is my html** :

```
<a href='#' id='cb'>mode<input type='checkbox' id='mode'></a>
```

**My Jquery** :

```
    $("#cb").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mode").prop("checked", !$("#mode").prop("checked"));
    })
```

**What I need** :

I need to be able to check the checkbox by clicking on href AND by clicking on the checkbox.

If this post is duplicate, i'm sorry but i didn't see it, link me the duplicate and i'll remove this.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fwzd08cw/)

Comment: Why do you need the checkbox inside the anchor?

Comment: I took a menu tabs on internet, and every menu option had <a>

Comment: You can try `$("#mode").click(function(e){ e.stopPropagation(); });` https://jsfiddle.net/fwzd08cw/3/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check tag name of target to prevent while clicking on input - https://jsfiddle.net/fwzd08cw/2/

```
$("#cb").click(function(e) {
    if((e.target).tagName == 'INPUT') return true; 
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#mode").prop("checked", !$("#mode").prop("checked"));
});
```

```js
$("#cb").click(function(e) {
  if((e.target).tagName == 'INPUT') return true; 
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#mode").prop("checked", !$("#mode").prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' id='cb'>mode<input type='checkbox' id='mode'></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code have two events 'click' when you has click on checkbox, the parent trigger the 'click' event of them.
You need use `event.stopPropagation()` function to negate the propagation of event from children to parent.

```js
$("#cb").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#mode').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  })
  $("#mode").prop("checked", !$("#mode").prop("checked"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' id='cb'>mode<input type='checkbox' id='mode'></a>
```

Comment: This binds a `click` event every time `#cb` is clicked. Don't do that

Answer (score 2):

Add style on input:

```
    pointer-events: none;
```

Comment: Nice one! But, we may need to check the browser compatibility for this!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, keep your input tag outside the anchor.

```
<a href='#' id='cb'> mode </a><input type='checkbox' id='mode'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **without** any JS code:

```
<a href='#' id='cb'><label>mode<input type='checkbox' id='mode'></label></a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fwzd08cw/5/

Answer (score 0):

The 'checking' is twice inverted when clicking on the checkbox,

Add : `$("#mode").click(function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });` to prevent this side effect of being inside the link.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `$('#cb, #mode')` to select both elements
- Use `$(this).is('a')` to check if href was the trigger and then check or uncheck accordingly
- In  every case do `e.stopPropagation()` to avoid calling click both times when checkbox is clicked 9one for input and one for href)

```js
$('#cb, #mode').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).is('a')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mode').prop('checked', !$('#mode').prop('checked'));
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#' id='cb'>mode<input type='checkbox' id='mode'></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you put checkobx inside the link but if you want a solution you can but the link inside a span like this

```
<a href='#' id='cb'><span id="mohamed">mode</span><input type='checkbox' id='mode'></a>


$("#mohamed").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#mode").prop("checked", !$("#mode").prop("checked"));
    })
```

check this pen http://codepen.io/mohamed_sobhy292/pen/wWPzoo